Ошибка с jquery
scripts.js:37 выдает Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, хотя все подключено.
Вот html:
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
    <script rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'scripts/scripts.js' %}"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <title>
        {% block title %}
        {% endblock title %}
    </title>
</head>
<body class="bg-dark">

{% include 'components/_navbar.html' %}

{% block main %}

{% endblock main %}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

и scripts.js:
$(".custom-carousel").owlCarousel({
  autoWidth: true,
  loop: true
});
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".custom-carousel .item").click(function () {
    $(".custom-carousel .item").not($(this)).removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});


скрипт с подключением jquery помечен как defer, т.е. будет загружен после того как будет завершен парсинг и загрузка html. Получается jquery используется раньше, чем он был импортирован (загружен)

Поставьте этот скрипт выше других скоиптов

А вы инициализировали этот знак доллара?
(function ($) {
Тут ваш код js
}) 
Либо вам следует вместо знака $ писать jQuery
